# Active Admin: two nested forms for two objects of the same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin, nested-forms

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :some_relation1
  belongs_to :some_relation2  # Same class as some_relation1
end
```

Inside the `MyModel` ActiveAdmin form page, I want to show two inner forms: one for `some_relation1` and one for `some_relation2`.

I'm doing it like this:

```
f.inputs 'Test 1' do
  f.semantic_fields_for(f.object.some_relation1 || f.object.build_some_relation1) do |inner_f|
    inner_f.inputs '' do
      # Some inputs
    end
  end
end

f.inputs 'Test 1' do
  f.semantic_fields_for(f.object.some_relation2 || f.object.build_some_relation2) do |inner_f|
    inner_f.inputs '' do
      # Some inputs
    end
  end
end
```

The first problem I had is that ActiveAdmin seems to generate the HTML input classes based on the underlying object's class, so the inputs for `some_relation1` and `some_relation2` would end up with the classes and clash.

At this point I tried to make a special class for `some_relation2`, that inherits its previous class, just so that ActiveAdmin generates unique HTML classes.
This works, but now I get this error when submitting the form:

```
SomeClass2(#70117816523800) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#70117783961220)
```

I'm at a loss here.
Does anyone know the correct way to do this, or a monkey patch to add this feature to ActiveAdmin?

Answer (score 1):

At first, my intention is to share something available on active admin which might works in your case. But as I am not so much confident about your question, can you please review my answer and let me know if this helps ?

ActiveAdmin.register Post do

```
form do |f|
  .......
  f.inputs do
    f.has_many :some_relation_one, :allow_destroy => true, as: :uniq_name ,:heading => 'Themes', :new_record => false do |cf|
      cf.input :title
    end
  end
  f.actions
 end
end
```

Also please make sure you add the accept_nested_attributes_for :some_relation_ship in your desired model to be accepted.

Comment: In your Post example, Post would have two belongs_to relationships. What I want is to show two nested forms for these relationships (which both “link” to a record of the same type). So I don't want to use `has_many` here unless it's the only solution, because it doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: in that case there is a solutions! You could change the form name and it can be handled through model and controller.

Comment: The following thing should work: You just have to manage getting those data in model/controller.

` f.has_many :some_relation_one, :allow_destroy => true, as: :uniq_name ,:heading => 'Themes', :new_record => false do |cf|`

Comment: preferred way is handling these stuffs in model. so your active admin controller won't make trouble and you won't need to override them.

Comment: okey great! I will be here to help you out as far as possible